# I want to know the run time of each test case in the code itself using pytest in data bricks

Tags: pytest, databricks, python-unittest, pytest-cov

I am using data bricks notebook. I have created a test_notebook.py which consists for test cases.
I started executing in another notebook using below code

```
import pytest
pyargs = ['dbfs/FileStore/test_notebook.py']
pytest.main(pyargs)
```

I am getting run time for all the test cases.
How can I see runtime for each testcase in the data bricks notebook itself?